# Make a dataframe from a json list

Tags: json, r

I would like **convert data from json in a data frame in R**. I tried with the package data.tree but i get only a data.frame with only NA...

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.tree)
library(magrittr)
data<-fromJSON("http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/nama_gdp_c?precision=1&geo=EU28&unit=EUR_HAB&time=2010&time=2011&indic_na=B1GM")
repos<-as.Node(data)
repos %>% ToDataFrameTable(valeur=function(x) x$repos$value,annee= function(x) x$repos$dimension$time$category$label)
```

**I tried this too**:

```
repos %>% ToDataFrameTable(valeur=function(x) x$value,annee= function(x) x$dimension$time$category$label)
```

But here there is just a two columns data empty

I tried directly this

```
as.data.frame(valeur=data$value,annee=data$dimension$time$category$label)
```

but i get this : 
"Error in as.data.frame(valeur = data$value, annee = data$dimension$time$category$label) : argument "x" is missing, with no default"

If someone know something...

Comment: what information are you trying to extract from that JSON object?

Comment: the value and the dates

Comment: AFAIK the `fromJSON` argument of the jsonlite package is looking to accept an array of objects, and the data coming back from that URL is not in an array format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(rjson)
js <- fromJSON(file="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/nama_gdp_c?precision=1&geo=EU28&unit=EUR_HAB&time=2010&time=2011&indic_na=B1GM")

df <- data.frame(years=stack(js$dimension$time$category$label)$value, 
                 value=stack(js$value)$value, 
                 country=stack(js$dimension$geo$category$label)$value)
df
```

Output is:

```
  years value                       country
1  2010 24400 European Union (28 countries)
2  2011 25100 European Union (28 countries)
```

Comment: Not exactly, more this : 
Annee Valeur
2010    24400
2011    25100

But maybe it's impossible because of the format of the data coming back that URL... I have maybe add a treatment.

Comment: If you can explain the desired output then we can think of the exact solution (means how exactly do you want to save this JSON data in your dataframe?)

Comment: I would like save this JSON in a data.frame, the best possible would be in columns, ("years","value","country"), which would be respectively in $dimension$time$category$index, $value and $dimension$geo$category$label